# Objective-C: Using "if else" statements inside -(void)drawRect to get a checkbox state?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, checkbox, nsview, drawrect

I am trying to design an interface where when the user clicks a checkbox, it will display an image in a `NSView` box. There are 12 checkboxes, and I have ... in my mind... a layout of if else statements to handle all the different combinations of checked boxes. I have laid out the if else statements inside the `-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect` declaration, but they do not seem to be working. (I am not getting errors). I have figured out that it does evaluate the if else statements correctly when the program is first initiated. But when I click the checkbox that activates an action containing a "`setNeedsDisplay:`", the "if else" statements are not reevaluated. (Which of course means I don't understand exactly how `setNeedsDisplay:` works.lol)

I put a couple `NSLog` statements in various places to see what was happening. I have one in the -(void)drawRect declaration to make sure that the `setNeedsDisplay:` was working. And it was. Whenever I click a checkbox, it activates setNeedsDisplay.
I put a `NSLog` also in two places in my "if else" statement:
One at the first part:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {

if ([cNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"C Natural Selected");
    NSPoint cNaturalPos;
    cNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
    NSImage * cNaturalImage;
    cNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"cNatural.png"];
    [cNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:cNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
else 

    if ([dFlat state] == NSOnState) {
        NSPoint dFlatPos;
        dFlatPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
        NSImage * dFlatImage;
        dFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"cSharp.png"];
        [dFlatImage dissolveToPoint:dFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
    else
          ......................
```

And one at the end of the first set of "if else" conditionals:

```
        if ([bNatural state] == NSOnState) {
            NSPoint bNaturalPos;
            bNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
            NSImage * bNaturalImage;
            bNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bNatural.png"];
            [bNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:bNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}

        else {
             NSLog(@"No First Note Selection.");
             NSPoint emptyStaffPos;
             emptyStaffPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
             NSImage * emptyStaffImage;
             emptyStaffImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"emptyStaff.png"];
             [emptyStaffImage dissolveToPoint:emptyStaffPos fraction:(1.0)];}
```

I would expect that when the program was first loaded, the "No First Note Selection" would appear in my console. And it does. What doesn't happen is, when I activate the "cNatural" checkbox, it instead displays the "No First Note Selection" string in the console. Its like it is not registering the state change of the checkbox.

To make sure I had the checkboxes properly connected in Interface Builder, I created this line of code that activates when the checkbox is toggled: (This code also includes the `setNeedsDisplay:`)

```
- (IBAction)rendStaffCanvas:(id)sender  {


[staffDrawingCanvas setNeedsDisplay:YES];

if ([cNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"C Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"C Natural checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([dFlat state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"D Flat checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"D Flat checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([dNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"D Natural checkbox: ON");
}
```

All of this displays as I would expect in the console, but the "if else" statements in the `-(void)drawRect` part just don't seem to be registering.

I have looked everywhere and can't find a solution to this. Any help will be much appreciated.

Here is the rather lengthy code for my .m file:

```
#import "StaffCanvas.h"

@implementation StaffCanvas

- (IBAction)rendStaffCanvas:(id)sender  {
[staffDrawingCanvas setNeedsDisplay:YES];
if ([cNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"C Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"C Natural checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([dFlat state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"D Flat checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"D Flat checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([dNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"D Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"D Natural checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([eFlat state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"E Flat checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"E Flat checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([eNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"E Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"E Natural checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([fNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"F Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"F Natural checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([gFlat state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"G Flat checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"G Flat checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([gNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"G Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"G Natural checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([aFlat state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"A Flat checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"A Flat checkbox: OFF");
}   
if ([aNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"A Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"A Natural checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([bFlat state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"B Flat checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"B Flat checkbox: OFF");
}
if ([bNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"B Natural checkbox: ON");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"B Natural checkbox: OFF");
}

}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {

if ([cNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSLog(@"C Natural Selected");
    NSPoint cNaturalPos;
    cNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
    NSImage * cNaturalImage;
    cNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"cNatural.png"];
    [cNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:cNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
else 

    if ([dFlat state] == NSOnState) {
        NSPoint dFlatPos;
        dFlatPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
        NSImage * dFlatImage;
        dFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"cSharp.png"];
        [dFlatImage dissolveToPoint:dFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
    else 
        if ([dNatural state] == NSOnState) {
            NSPoint dNaturalPos;
            dNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
            NSImage * dNaturalImage;
            dNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dNatural.png"];
            [dNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:dNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
        else 
            if ([eFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                NSPoint eFlatPos;
                eFlatPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                NSImage * eFlatImage;
                eFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"eFlat.png"];
                [eFlatImage dissolveToPoint:eFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
            else 
                if ([eNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                    NSPoint eNaturalPos;
                    eNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                    NSImage * eNaturalImage;
                    eNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"eNatural.png"];
                    [eNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:eNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                else 
                    if ([fNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                        NSPoint fNaturalPos;
                        fNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                        NSImage * fNaturalImage;
                        fNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"fNatural.png"];
                        [fNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:fNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                    else  
                        if ([gFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                            NSPoint fSharpPos;
                            fSharpPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                            NSImage * fSharpImage;
                            fSharpImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"fSharp.png"];
                            [fSharpImage dissolveToPoint:fSharpPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                        else 
                            if ([gNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                                NSPoint gNaturalPos;
                                gNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                                NSImage * gNaturalImage;
                                gNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"gNatural.png"];
                                [gNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:gNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                            else  
                                if ([aFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                                    NSPoint aFlatPos;
                                    aFlatPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                                    NSImage * aFlatImage;
                                    aFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"aFlat.png"];
                                    [aFlatImage dissolveToPoint:aFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                else  
                                    if ([aNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                                        NSPoint aNaturalPos;
                                        aNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                                        NSImage * aNaturalImage;
                                        aNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"aNatural.png"];
                                        [aNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:aNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                    else  
                                        if ([bFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                                            NSPoint bFlatPos;
                                            bFlatPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                                            NSImage * bFlatImage;
                                            bFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bFlat.png"];
                                            [bFlatImage dissolveToPoint:bFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                        else 
                                            if ([bNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                                                NSPoint bNaturalPos;
                                                bNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                                                NSImage * bNaturalImage;
                                                bNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bNatural.png"];
                                                [bNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:bNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                            else {
                                                NSLog(@"No First Note Selection.");
                                                NSPoint emptyStaffPos;
                                                emptyStaffPos = NSMakePoint(35, 0);
                                                NSImage * emptyStaffImage;
                                                emptyStaffImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"emptyStaff.png"];
                                                [emptyStaffImage dissolveToPoint:emptyStaffPos fraction:(1.0)];}



if ([dFlat state] == NSOnState) {
    NSPoint dFlatPos;
    dFlatPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
    NSImage * dFlatImage;
    dFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"cSharp.png"];
    [dFlatImage dissolveToPoint:dFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
else 
    if ([dNatural state] == NSOnState) {
        NSPoint dNaturalPos;
        dNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
        NSImage * dNaturalImage;
        dNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dNatural.png"];
        [dNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:dNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
    else 
        if ([eFlat state] == NSOnState) {
            NSPoint eFlatPos;
            eFlatPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
            NSImage * eFlatImage;
            eFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"eFlat.png"];
            [eFlatImage dissolveToPoint:eFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
        else 
            if ([eNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                NSPoint eNaturalPos;
                eNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                NSImage * eNaturalImage;
                eNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"eNatural.png"];
                [eNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:eNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
            else 
                if ([fNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                    NSPoint fNaturalPos;
                    fNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                    NSImage * fNaturalImage;
                    fNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"fNatural.png"];
                    [fNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:fNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                else 
                    if ([gFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                        NSPoint fSharpPos;
                        fSharpPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                        NSImage * fSharpImage;
                        fSharpImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"fSharp.png"];
                        [fSharpImage dissolveToPoint:fSharpPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                    else 
                        if ([gNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                            NSPoint gNaturalPos;
                            gNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                            NSImage * gNaturalImage;
                            gNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"gNatural.png"];
                            [gNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:gNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                        else 
                            if ([aFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                                NSPoint aFlatPos;
                                aFlatPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                                NSImage * aFlatImage;
                                aFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"aFlat.png"];
                                [aFlatImage dissolveToPoint:aFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                            else 
                                if ([aNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                                    NSPoint aNaturalPos;
                                    aNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                                    NSImage * aNaturalImage;
                                    aNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"aNatural.png"];
                                    [aNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:aNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                else 
                                    if ([bFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                                        NSPoint bFlatPos;
                                        bFlatPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                                        NSImage * bFlatImage;
                                        bFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bFlat.png"];
                                        [bFlatImage dissolveToPoint:bFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                    else 
                                        if ([bNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                                            NSPoint bNaturalPos;
                                            bNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                                            NSImage * bNaturalImage;
                                            bNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bNatural.png"];
                                            [bNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:bNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                        else {
                                            NSPoint emptyStaffPos;
                                            emptyStaffPos = NSMakePoint(70, 0);
                                            NSImage * emptyStaffImage;
                                            emptyStaffImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"emptyStaff.png"];
                                            [emptyStaffImage dissolveToPoint:emptyStaffPos fraction:(1.0)];}


if ([dNatural state] == NSOnState) {
    NSPoint dNaturalPos;
    dNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
    NSImage * dNaturalImage;
    dNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"dNatural.png"];
    [dNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:dNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
else 
    if ([eFlat state] == NSOnState) {
        NSPoint eFlatPos;
        eFlatPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
        NSImage * eFlatImage;
        eFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"eFlat.png"];
        [eFlatImage dissolveToPoint:eFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
    else 
        if ([eNatural state] == NSOnState) {
            NSPoint eNaturalPos;
            eNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
            NSImage * eNaturalImage;
            eNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"eNatural.png"];
            [eNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:eNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
        else 
            if ([fNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                NSPoint fNaturalPos;
                fNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                NSImage * fNaturalImage;
                fNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"fNatural.png"];
                [fNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:fNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
            else 
                if ([gFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                    NSPoint fSharpPos;
                    fSharpPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                    NSImage * fSharpImage;
                    fSharpImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"fSharp.png"];
                    [fSharpImage dissolveToPoint:fSharpPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                else 
                    if ([gNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                        NSPoint gNaturalPos;
                        gNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                        NSImage * gNaturalImage;
                        gNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"gNatural.png"];
                        [gNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:gNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                    else 
                        if ([aFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                            NSPoint aFlatPos;
                            aFlatPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                            NSImage * aFlatImage;
                            aFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"aFlat.png"];
                            [aFlatImage dissolveToPoint:aFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                        else 
                            if ([aNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                                NSPoint aNaturalPos;
                                aNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                                NSImage * aNaturalImage;
                                aNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"aNatural.png"];
                                [aNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:aNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                            else 
                                if ([bFlat state] == NSOnState) {
                                    NSPoint bFlatPos;
                                    bFlatPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                                    NSImage * bFlatImage;
                                    bFlatImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bFlat.png"];
                                    [bFlatImage dissolveToPoint:bFlatPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                else 
                                    if ([bNatural state] == NSOnState) {
                                        NSPoint bNaturalPos;
                                        bNaturalPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                                        NSImage * bNaturalImage;
                                        bNaturalImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"bNatural.png"];
                                        [bNaturalImage dissolveToPoint:bNaturalPos fraction:(1.0)];}
                                    else {
                                        NSPoint emptyStaffPos;
                                        emptyStaffPos = NSMakePoint(105, 0);
                                        NSImage * emptyStaffImage;
                                        emptyStaffImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"emptyStaff.png"];
                                        [emptyStaffImage dissolveToPoint:emptyStaffPos fraction:(1.0)];}

NSLog(@"Redisplayed.");
NSPoint clefPos;
clefPos = NSMakePoint(0, 0);
NSImage * clefImage;
clefImage = [NSImage imageNamed:@"clefStart.png"];
[clefImage dissolveToPoint:clefPos fraction:(1.0)];


}   

@end
```

Comment: Can't speak to your issue cause your code is kinda overwhelming. Find a simple, tiny example that doesn't work. (In doing so, your code could be much simpler and tinier, as it appears your if/else statements only execute one of three very similar blocks of code.)

Comment: I added a bit of simpler code under the -(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect statement. Even if I have the appropriate checkbox selected when the program is running, it doesn't think that it is. I hope that makes more sense: Sorry... I guess I can't put the code in the comment. It was like this....    -(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect   {                        if ([cNatural sate] == NSOnstate) {                                  NSLog (@"C Natural ON");                                               }     else { NSLog (@"Nothing Happened.");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isnt a particularly good way to approach this as you are treating your view as the model. Read about the Model View Controller (MVC) pattern if you havent already.

I would have a either a boolean NSUserDefault per switch or a obj-c property depending on how persistent you want this to be.

So cook up your XIB with your switches and then bind (its the 4th from left in the inspector with the two greenish blobs) the values of the switches to your properties.

```
    @class FooController : NSObject
    {

    BOOL switch1;
    BOOL switch2;

    }

@property (readwrite,assign) BOOL switch1;
@property (readwrite,assign) BOOL switch2;
```

Then assuming this is the owner object for the NIB

```
@class FooController

@synthesise switch1,switch2;

-(void)awakeFromNib
{

self.switch1 = YES; //switch1 starts on 
self.switch2 = NO; //switch2 starts off


[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"switch1" options:0 context:NULL];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"switch2" options:0 context:NULL];


}

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context
{
if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"switch1"]) { //do things related to switch1 }
else if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"switch2"]) { //do things related to switch2 }
etc...
}

@end
```

The self observing self thing looks a little weird but it means when the switch bound to the corresponding property is changed in the interface you get to know about it. And you dont have write a shed load of get/set methods.

The NSUserDefaults object is equally observable with this method

```
[[NSUserDefaultsController sharedUserDefaultsController] addObserver:self 
                                                          forKeyPath:@"switch1" 
                                                             options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) 
                                                             context:NULL];
```

Any change to the value on your model is reflected in the view and any change in the view is noted in the observation protocol

Check out this doc http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/

Comment: The Bindings Inspector is also ⌘4. All the Inspectors (at least in the IB that comes with Xcode 3; I haven't used Xcode 4) are numbered like this.

Comment: I managed to get everything in your suggestions implemented into my code. The problem is (and I likely am having a fundamental misunderstanding of how variables work): the variables don't seem to be carrying into my -(void)drawRect method. In the -(void)observeValueForKeyPath I put the if conditionals to set the variable "image1" to the name of the file of the png for the drawRect to render as an NSString *image1=@"cNatural.png". In the voidRect, I have NSImage *StaffImage1=[NSImage imageNamed:image1]; When I add an NSLog to this area, a null value is returned.

Comment: using image1=@"cNatural.png" will be only scoped to the function you called it in. declare these ivars as (readwrite,copy) properties like the bools so you'll have self.image1 = @"cNatural.png" . Dont forget to set to nil (self.image1=nil) in the dealloc override or you will leak. basically the string is being autoreleased so you need to keep a copy to give it scope in the drawrect

Answer (score 5):

In addition to making your checkboxes reflect Boolean values your controller owns, rather than own those values themselves, and moving this logic to the controller, you should also burninate most of that copied-and-pasted code.

It looks like you're doing the same thing for every case, only really varying the image, so use the same `position` variable (with the same value) and the same `image` variable for all the cases.

Do away with the `if` statements. Set the checkboxes' tags in IB, and in your controller's action method for the checkboxes, use the sender's tag to determine which image to show. (Whether you do this with an array or a dictionary is up to you, but you'll have to set it up ahead of time, such as in `init`, either way.)

You may want to make a plist file containing an array or dictionary of image names and load that in your `init` method. You can have another method that attempts to retrieve the NSImage from a dictionary with the tag numbers as keys and, if the tag is not in that dictionary, uses the tags-to-names dictionary (from the plist file) to get the image name, loads the image using that name, and stores the image in the tags-to-images dictionary for future retrievals. You'll call this method when a checkbox is clicked, passing the checkbox's tag, and handing off the image it returns to your custom view to display.

If you are targeting Snow Leopard, you can use [NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/) instead of NSMutableDictionary for the tags-to-images mapping. This enables you to set a limit on how many images you keep loaded at a time.

By the way, `dissolveToPoint:fraction:` is deprecated since Snow Leopard. You should use `drawAtPoint:fromRect:operation:fraction:` instead. Pass `NSZeroRect` for the source rectangle to use the entire image.

Also, if you really do mean for the user to only be able to select one image at a time, you should use radio buttons, not checkboxes. Implement that as an NSMatrix containing NSButtonCells; the easiest way is to create a single radio button, then option-resize it in IB. The cells are what you should set the tags and actions of. Checkboxes would be appropriate only if the user can select multiple images to be combined in some way (e.g., compositing them together).

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick and detailed answers. They will help immensely in what to read up on and learn next. It was nice to have confirmation that my approach was wrong, as I figured it had to be. Maybe it will help if I explain better what I am trying to do. I have, in the user interface, a clockface of checkboxes with each representing a musical pitch. I would like to have it function where when the user clicks a set of these pitches, it will bring up images of them represented as notes. Since they will be able to choose more than one note, the radio buttons would not work.

Comment: So the images must appear in order. So if checkbox 1, 4, and 5 are checked I want to bring up those images side by side. Although it would be easier to just have each checkbox pick between two images, I don't want large spaces between the images that would result if they chose checkbox 1, 8, and 12... for example. In that case I would want image 1, 8, and 12 to appear together. that is why I devised the crazy, lengthy if else setup. I will read up on the different approaches that you all gave me here and see if I can implement that somehow.

Comment: If someone knows of other methods I should read up on, I would truly appreciate it. I am learning  slowly but surely.

Comment: @Jess: OK, so your use of checkboxes is justified, since you are combining zero or more images. You'll want to change the destination point, though, so as not to simply draw all the images on top of each other. Each image's size (particularly the size's width, if you're laying them out horizontally) will be useful to you here.

Comment: Before I revised my code (and realized my logic was faulty with how it was set up) I have several different if else's. Each new set adjusted the coordinates. Now I have chosen a simpler way to display the images, but I can't get variables I establish outside of drawRect to translate into the drawRect. I am total Noob... haha

Comment: Jess: Local variables are just that: Local. They go away when the method ends. You need to either compute the point for each image in `drawRect:` or keep an array of points in an instance variable.